# How to fetch comments with most likes or replies on a YouTube video using YouTube Data API?

Tags: java, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

So far, I have managed to collect first 100 comments on a video using YouTube Data API in my Java program shown below.

public class CommentHandling {

```
/**
 * Define a global instance of a YouTube object, which will be used to make
 * YouTube Data API requests.
 */
private static YouTube youtube;

/**
 * List, reply to comment threads; list, update, moderate, mark and delete
 * replies.
 *
 * @param args command line args (not used).
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
    // authenticated user's account and requires requests to use an SSL connection.
    List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

    try {
        // Authorize the request.
        Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "commentthreads");

        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-commentthreads-sample").build();

        // Prompt the user for the ID of a video to comment on.
        // Retrieve the video ID that the user is commenting to.
        String videoId = getVideoId();
        System.out.println("You chose " + videoId + " to subscribe.");

        // All the available methods are used in sequence just for the sake
        // of an example.

        // Call the YouTube Data API's commentThreads.list method to
        // retrieve video comment threads.
        CommentThreadListResponse videoCommentsListResponse = youtube.commentThreads()
                .list("snippet, replies").setVideoId(videoId)
                .setMaxResults(new Long(100)).setTextFormat("html").execute();
        List<CommentThread> videoComments = videoCommentsListResponse.getItems();

        if (videoComments.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Can't get video comments.");
        } else {
            // Print information from the API response.
            System.out
                    .println("\n================== Returned Video Comments ==================\n");
            for (CommentThread videoComment : videoComments) {
                CommentSnippet snippet = videoComment.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment()
                        .getSnippet();
                System.out.println("  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());
                System.out.println("  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay());
                System.out
                        .println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode()
                + " : " + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Prompt the user to enter a video ID. Then return the ID.
 */
private static String getVideoId() throws IOException {

    String videoId = "";

    System.out.print("Please enter a video id: ");
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    videoId = bReader.readLine();

    return videoId;
}
```

But I am interested in collecting the top comments (either by likes or replies on a comment) on a video. These are the comments which are usually on the first page of the video when sorted by using "Top comments" filter.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: means you want to get top level comment